# animation not works in the non-initial UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` called `loadingView` shows some `UIActivityIndicatorView`-like animation. There are two `UIViewController`s that all have such `UIView`.

The initial `UIViewController`'s code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 120, 120)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
}
```

Also it has a button to present the second `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
    SecondViewController *sVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:sVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The second `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 120, 120)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
}
```

As you can see, the two `UIViewController`s has the same `viewDidLoad` method code.

The `loadingView` works well in the initial `UIViewController`.

But in the second `UIViewController`, the `loadingView` only displays the black frame( I set the background colour to black).

Here is my `loadingView` implement code:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_DOT 15
#define DURATION 1.5

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.replicatorLayer = [[CAReplicatorLayer alloc] init];
        self.replicatorLayer.frame = frame;
        self.replicatorLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
        self.replicatorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.86].CGColor;
        self.replicatorLayer.position = self.center;
        self.replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = DURATION/NUMBER_OF_DOT;
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.replicatorLayer];

        float size = frame.size.width*14/200;
        self.dot = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        self.dot.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size);
        self.dot.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/5);
        self.dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        self.dot.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.dot.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.dot.cornerRadius = 1.5;
        self.dot.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);    
        [self.replicatorLayer addSublayer:self.dot];

        self.replicatorLayer.instanceCount = NUMBER_OF_DOT;
        float angle = 2*M_PI/NUMBER_OF_DOT;
        self.replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);

        self.shrink = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
        self.shrink.keyPath  = @"transform.scale";
        self.shrink.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        self.shrink.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];
        self.shrink.duration = DURATION;
        self.shrink.repeatCount = INFINITY;

        [self.dot addAnimation:self.shrink forKey:nil];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you give detail for this line

SecondViewController *sVC = [[HMPlaySceneViewController alloc] init];

You alloc HMPlaySceneViewController type object and give in reference of SecondViewController class.

Comment: @Shreyank My fault. I have updated the code. `SecondViewController` is excatlly the `HMPlaySceneViewController`.  I renamed `HMPlaySceneViewController` to simplify the question but I forgot to update code.

Comment: I check your code. I face the issue when presenting View controller. but when i tried for push viewcontroller it works fine. Will check and let you know what is issue with presenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 120, 120)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
}
```

Put this code in viewDidAppear of SecondViewController so it works in present mode as well.

Comment: I have also found the reason.  I should not perform any animation in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: But why the animation works well in the initial `UIViewController`?